# How to set the year list in Primefaces' calendar component?

Tags: primefaces, calendar

Do exist any way to set the year list of the calendar component of primefaces?

Comment: You should provide an example.

Answer (score 11):

for year list you can use `navigator="true"` attribute of primefaces in `p:calendar` tag and for year range `c-100:c+100` (will show the year range starting from 100 years back to 100 years forward in future.

so code will look like

```
<p:calendar id="someid"  yearRange="c-100:c+100" navigator="true"/>
```

Comment: Then you still start with what date? Setting the 'default' year is what the question is from what I can see

Comment: @Anubhav unfortunately not. the start date is the currentdate in the calendar object, which is pretty bad IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

If you need only a year list, you can do:

```xml
<p:calendar value="#{backingBean.date}" navigator="true" yearRange="-100" showOn="button" />
```

that wil show you a list with the current year, and one hundred years ago.

Regards

Comment: I think the OP wants to set a different year and not the current.  E.g. if user are between 20 and 40 years old you might want to set the current year to 30 years back so it is less navigating.

Comment: this shows an error on the web console: 'TypeError: N[1] is undefined' due to the yearRange